# How to apply styling to a specific item in an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I'm trying to make a simple todo in react. I want to be able to click in the button next to the todo text and mark it as complete, with a line passing through it, so I guess the point of the button would be to toggle between the two stylings. But I don't know how to apply the styling to that specific todo. Here's my code so far:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function App() {
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([])

  const toggleComplete = (i) => {
    setTodos(todos.map((todo, k) => k === i ? {
      ...todo, complete: !todo.complete
    } : todo))
  }

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    const todo = event.target[0].value

    setTodos((prevTodos) => {
      return [...prevTodos, {
        userTodo: todo, completed: false, id: Math.random().toString()
      }]
    })
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input placeholder='name'></input>
        <button type='submit'>submit</button>
      </form>

      <ul>
        {todos.map((todos) => <li key={todos.id}>

          <h4>{
          todos.completed ? <s><h4>{todos.userTodo}</h4></s> : <h4>{todos.userTodo}</h4>}
          </h4>

          <button onClick={toggleComplete}>Mark as complete</button>
          
        </li>)}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see that the `toggleComplete` function takes a parameter `i` which is the id of the todo, so you should call it like `onClick={() => toggleComplete(todos.id)}`.

However this still didn't work since you are assigning random numbers as strings as id to the todos then iterating over the array.

As Alex pointed out, there's a bug in your code regarding the completed toggle, so I fixed it and here's a working version of the code you can take a look at and improve:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);

  const toggleComplete = (i) => {
    setTodos(
      todos.map((todo, k) => {
        return k === i
          ? {
              ...todo,
              completed: !todo.completed
            }
          : todo;
      })
    );
  };

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const todo = event.target[0].value;

    setTodos((prevTodos) => {
      return [
        ...prevTodos,
        {
          userTodo: todo,
          completed: false,
          id: prevTodos.length
        }
      ];
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input placeholder="name"></input>
        <button type="submit">submit</button>
      </form>

      <ul>
        {todos.map((todo) => (
          <li key={todo.id}>
            {todo.completed ? (
              <s>
                <p>{todo.userTodo}</p>
              </s>
            ) : (
              <p>{todo.userTodo}</p>
            )}

            <button onClick={() => toggleComplete(todo.id)}>
              Mark as complete
            </button>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I edited the html tags because codesandbox complained about the h4 tags, and I fixed the index issue using `prevTodos.length` so k will match i when you iterate through the array.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 problems in your code as i see:

1. typo in the `toggleComplete` function

**Fix:** the following code `complete: !todo.complete` shopuld be `completed: !todo.completed` as this is the name of the key that you're setting below on `handleSubmit`.

2. the `toggleComplete` function receives as an argument the javascript `event` object and you are comparing it with the `key` here:
   `(todo, k) => k === i`

> (see more here:
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/click_event)

Fix: You can modify the lines of code for the todo render as follows:

```
        {todos.map((todo, index) => <li key={todo.id}>

            <React.Fragment>{
                todo.completed ? <del><h4>{todo.userTodo}</h4></del> : <h4>{todo.userTodo}</h4>}
            </React.Fragment>

            <button onClick={() => {toggleComplete(index)}}>Mark as complete</button>

        </li>)}
```